# boost units - needed libraries

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost 1.58 on a Ubuntu 16.04 system.

At the moment I am working with **boost units**. When using `std::numeric_limits` I am missing some library that has to be linked. Which library do I have to link?

```
// compiled with g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -O0

#include <boost/units/limits.hpp>
#include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/length.hpp>
#include <boost/units/unit.hpp>

using boost::units::si::meters;
using Meter = boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::length, double>;


int main() {
    bool a1 = std::numeric_limits<Meter>::is_specialized;
    bool const& a2 = std::numeric_limits<Meter>::is_specialized; // undefined reference to is_specialized
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
$ g++test.cpp -std=c++11 -O0    
/tmp/ccuHYpq5.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `std::numeric_limits<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::unit<boost::units::list<boost::units::dim<boost::units::length_base_dimension, boost::units::static_rational<1l, 1l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::homogeneous_system<boost::units::list<boost::units::si::meter_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::scaled_base_unit<boost::units::cgs::gram_base_unit, boost::units::scale<10l, boost::units::static_rational<3l, 1l> > >, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::second_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::ampere_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::kelvin_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::mole_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::candela_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::steradian_base_unit, boost::units::dimensionless_type> > > > > > > > > >, void>, double> >::is_specialized'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is this a boost bug? Or am I missing the correct header file?

Comment: `#include <limits>` ?

Comment: Thats not a library. Its a header. I am looking for the corrosponding library which contains the symbols for `#include <boost/units/limits>`

Comment: Why do you want a const reference? I'm pretty sure `std::numeric_limits` members are not specified to have a definition, so you should not odr-use them.

Comment: Boost adds specializations to `std::numeric_limits`, but the original/generic definition isn't visible unless you `#include <limits>`, which is why the error occurs at the linking stage.

On the off chance that isn't the issue, try changing `std::numeric_limits` to `boost::numeric_limits` in your code.

Comment: @RayHamel `#include <boost/units/limits.hpp>` already includes `#include <limits>`. So that doesn't change anything. @Quentin it seems like it, but doesn't that make my program ill-formed?

Comment: Have you *tried* adding `#include <limits>` to your own file? Even if it "seems" like that's not the issue. It's likely that your Boost is defining some macro that is causing it not to be included or hiding its definitions, even though it seems like it "should." Also, it's just good practice to explicitly include all the header files you're using in your own files, not to rely on them being included, as an undocumented implementation detail, in other library headers.

Comment: yes I have added `#include <limits>` but it doesnt change anything.